# Tensorflow + Keras + Convolution2d: ValueError: Filter must not be larger than the input: Filter: (5, 5) Input: (3, 350)

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, convolution, keras

I have been trying to run the code below which I got from [here](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html) and even though I have changed almost nothing other than the image size (350,350 instead of 150, 150) is still cannot get it to work. I am getting the above filter error (in title) which I do comprehend but I am not doing it wrong so I don't understand this. It basically says that I cannot have more nodes than inputs, correct?

I was able to eventually hack my way to a solution by changing this line:

```
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 5, 5, border_mode='valid', input_shape=(3, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT)))
```

with this:

```
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 5, 5, border_mode='valid', input_shape=(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, 3)))
```

but I would still like to understand why this worked.

Here is the code below along with the error I am getting. Would appreciate some help (I am using Python Anaconda 2.7.11).

```
# IMPORT LIBRARIES --------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
import glob
import tensorflow
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from settings import RAW_DATA_ROOT

# GLOBAL VARIABLES --------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
TRAIN_PATH = RAW_DATA_ROOT + "/train/"
TEST_PATH = RAW_DATA_ROOT + "/test/"

IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT = 350, 350

NB_TRAIN_SAMPLES = len(glob.glob(TRAIN_PATH + "*"))
NB_VALIDATION_SAMPLES = len(glob.glob(TEST_PATH + "*"))
NB_EPOCH = 50

# FUNCTIONS ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
def baseline_model():
    """
    The Keras library provides wrapper classes to allow you to use neural network models developed
    with Keras in scikit-learn. The code snippet below is used to construct a simple stack of 3
    convolution layers with a ReLU activation and followed by max-pooling layers. This is very
    similar to the architectures that Yann LeCun advocated in the 1990s for image classification
    (with the exception of ReLU).
    :return: The training model.
    """
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Convolution2D(32, 5, 5, border_mode='valid', input_shape=(3, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT)))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

    model.add(Convolution2D(32, 5, 5, border_mode='valid'))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

    model.add(Convolution2D(64, 5, 5, border_mode='valid'))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

    # Add a  fully connected layer layer that converts our 3D feature maps to 1D feature vectors
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(64))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))

    # Use a dropout layer to reduce over-fitting, by preventing a layer from seeing twice the exact
    # same pattern (works by switching off a node once in a while in different epochs...). This
    # will also serve as out output layer.
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(8))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))

    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  optimizer='adam',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model

def train_model(model):
    """
    Simple script that uses the baseline model and returns a trained model.
    :param model: model
    :return: model
    """

    # Define the augmentation configuration we will use for training
    TRAIN_DATAGEN = ImageDataGenerator(
            rescale=1. / 255,
            shear_range=0.2,
            zoom_range=0.2,
            horizontal_flip=True)

    # Build the train generator
    TRAIN_GENERATOR = TRAIN_DATAGEN.flow_from_directory(
            TRAIN_PATH,
            target_size=(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT),
            batch_size=32,
            class_mode='categorical')

    TEST_DATAGEN = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

    # Build the validation generator
    TEST_GENERATOR = TEST_DATAGEN.flow_from_directory(
            TEST_PATH,
            target_size=(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT),
            batch_size=32,
            class_mode='categorical')

    # Train model
    model.fit_generator(
            TRAIN_GENERATOR,
            samples_per_epoch=NB_TRAIN_SAMPLES,
            nb_epoch=NB_EPOCH,
            validation_data=TEST_GENERATOR,
            nb_val_samples=NB_VALIDATION_SAMPLES)

    # Always save your weights after training or during training
    model.save_weights('first_try.h5') 

# END OF FILE -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
```

and the error:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Training set: 0 files.
Test set: 0 files.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/christoshadjinikolis/GitHub_repos/datareplyuk/ODSC_Facial_Sentiment_Analysis/src/model/__init__.py", line 79, in <module>
    model = baseline_model()
  File "/Users/christoshadjinikolis/GitHub_repos/datareplyuk/ODSC_Facial_Sentiment_Analysis/src/model/training_module.py", line 31, in baseline_model
    model.add(Convolution2D(32, 5, 5, border_mode='valid', input_shape=(3, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT)))
  File "/Users/christoshadjinikolis/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 276, in add
    layer.create_input_layer(batch_input_shape, input_dtype)
  File "/Users/christoshadjinikolis/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 370, in create_input_layer
    self(x)
  File "/Users/christoshadjinikolis/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 514, in __call__
    self.add_inbound_node(inbound_layers, node_indices, tensor_indices)
  File "/Users/christoshadjinikolis/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 572, in add_inbound_node
    Node.create_node(self, inbound_layers, node_indices, tensor_indices)
  File "/Users/christoshadjinikolis/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 149, in create_node
    output_tensors = to_list(outbound_layer.call(input_tensors[0], mask=input_masks[0]))
  File "/Users/christoshadjinikolis/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/layers/convolutional.py", line 466, in call
    filter_shape=self.W_shape)
  File "/Users/christoshadjinikolis/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 1579, in conv2d
    x = tf.nn.conv2d(x, kernel, strides, padding=padding)
  File "/Users/christoshadjinikolis/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_nn_ops.py", line 394, in conv2d
    data_format=data_format, name=name)
  File "/Users/christoshadjinikolis/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 703, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/Users/christoshadjinikolis/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2319, in create_op
    set_shapes_for_outputs(ret)
  File "/Users/christoshadjinikolis/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1711, in set_shapes_for_outputs
    shapes = shape_func(op)
  File "/Users/christoshadjinikolis/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py", line 246, in conv2d_shape
    padding)
  File "/Users/christoshadjinikolis/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py", line 184, in get2d_conv_output_size
    (row_stride, col_stride), padding_type)
  File "/Users/christoshadjinikolis/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py", line 149, in get_conv_output_size
    "Filter: %r Input: %r" % (filter_size, input_size))
ValueError: Filter must not be larger than the input: Filter: (5, 5) Input: (3, 350)
```

Comment: Tensorflow typically uses NHWC format, which means the shape is specified as (batch_size, height, width, channels). From a quick look at the keras documentation (https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/), one option of keras is to specify the shape as (channels, height, width), and batch_size separately, which is also the case in your example. So looks like your example is correct, and should have worked, and the fix doesn't make sense. If I were you, I would use pdb to step through the call stack to find out where exactly the wrong shape is handed from keras to tensorflow.

Comment: Thanks, I' ll have a look later next week and post my findings.

Comment: Another possibility is that the example is meant for some framework other than Tensorflow, and this framework specifies the shape with order (channels, height, width). For Tensorflow, you might indeed need to change the order. But this puzzles me as well, because I think keras is supposed to be portable across different machine learning frameworks.

Comment: Looking more into this: https://keras.io/backend/ You can search for  [batch, channels, height, width] in this page. Now it looks like the shape order indeed needs to be changed for Tensorflow, and keras doesn't seem to handle it internally/automatically. BTW, I know little about keras; some keras expert here could definitely give better advice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the order of input_shape() changes depending the backend you are using (tensorflow or theano).

The best solution I found was defining this order in the file `~/.keras/keras.json`.

`Try to use the theano order with tensorflow backend, or theano order with theano backend.`

Create the keras directory in your home and create the keras json: `mkdir ~/.keras && touch ~/.keras/keras.json`

```
{
    "image_dim_ordering": "th", 
    "epsilon": 1e-07, 
    "floatx": "float32", 
    "backend": "tensorflow"
}
```

Comment: ~/.keras/keras.json may very well already exist. Modifying it may serve you better than creating a new one, since there may be other settings you don't want to change.

Comment: @pyan the command I mention to create a **directory** and the **keras.json** it will work only if there is no **keras.json** file. Therefore it's safe to run, and will not modify the existing file.

Answer (score 5):

Just encountered the same problem myself, when I was following a tutorial. As pointed out by @Yao Zhang, the error is caused by the order in the `input_shape`. There are multiple ways to solve the problem.

- Option 1: Change the order in `input_shape`

The line of your code

```
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 5, 5, border_mode='valid', input_shape=(3, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT)))
```

should be changed to

```
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 5, 5, border_mode='valid', input_shape=(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, 3)))
```

which should be fine then.

- Option 2: Specify `image_dim_ordering` in your layers
- Option 3: Modify the keras configuration file by changing 'tf' to 'th' in your ~/.keras/keras.json