# regarding set_image_dim_ordering('tf') in keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

When experimenting with a Keras implementation, I did as follows:

```
from keras import backend as K
K.set_image_dim_ordering('tf')
```

It generates the following error message. What does it mean? I think set_image_dim_ordering is included in Keras.

```
File "train.py", line 14, in <module>
K.set_image_dim_ordering('tf')
```

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'set_image_dim_ordering'

Comment: Which version of keras do you have? For me, on `1.1.0`, it works.

Comment: Hi, I just test it, The version 1.0.3  Since I am using it on a public environment, it may not easy for me to get it updated soon. Are there any ways for me to set this parameter using the current version? Thanks.

Comment: I have no idea. Can you include the details in the question itself?

Comment: Hi, sygi, the background is this. I am trying to test the code presented here https://github.com/jocicmarko/ultrasound-nerve-segmentation/blob/master/train.py   which uses Theano as backend for Keras. I am using Tensorflow, so I am trying to modify the code to make it run on Tensorflow. The first thing I change is K.set_image_dim_ordering('tf') which was set as 'th' in the original code.

Comment: There are couple of other ways to do it. Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39848466/tensorflow-keras-convolution2d-valueerror-filter-must-not-be-larger-than-t/39882814#39882814

Answer (score 5):

Keras is Deep Learning framework which can uses from '**TensorFlow**' , '**Theano**'  and '**CNTK**' as a backend.
Every backend has its own preferences to use the channel ordering

- **Theano**: channel first order
- **Tensorflow**: channel last order
- **CNTK**: channel last order

if you are using '**Theano**' as a backend, you should set "**channels_first** order" and after import keras library you can use this line of code:

```
keras.backend.set_image_data_format('channels_first')
```

and data shape is as follows : (**channel**, rows, columns).

**Note**: channel order in your **"data shape"** should be equal to channel order in the **"backend"**. for example if you are using **Tensorflow** as backend, then the input shape of your data should be **channel last order**(for RGB image: (rows, columns, **channel**))

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

`from keras import backend as K
K.tensorflow_backend.set_image_dim_ordering('th')`

Comment: Does not work in Keras version 2.3.1 do you have another alternative.

Answer (score 2):

In Keras 2.3.1 uses:

```
from keras as backend as K
K.common.set_image_dim_ordering('th')
```

Yes. Its working for me for the Keras version 2.3.1

Comment: When posting code please use proper formatting as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting. For inline code you can use single backticks `\`` and for blocks of code you can use three of them. Optionally you can also provide the language for syntax highlighting for code blocks e.g. `\`\`\`python`

Answer (score 0):

In Keras 2.3.1 uses:

```
from keras as backend as K
K.common.set_image_dim_ordering('th')
```

Answer (score 0):

What version are you using?

*"In the backend, `set_image_ordering` and `image_ordering` are now `set_data_format` and `data_format.`"*

[Keras 2.0 Release notes](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/wiki/Keras-2.0-release-notes)

Answer (score 0):

For tensorflow V2.3

```
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
# to know the image order
K.image_data_format()
# to set the image order
K.set_image_data_format()
```

Answer (score 0):

To support both new and old versions of Keras, for theano and tensorflow, you can use this:

```
try:
    if K.backend() == 'theano':
        K.set_image_data_format('channels_first')
    else:
        K.set_image_data_format('channels_last')
except AttributeError:
    if K._BACKEND == 'theano':
        K.set_image_dim_ordering('th')
    else:
        K.set_image_dim_ordering('tf')
```

(taken from "https://github.com/Arsey/keras-transfer-learning-for-oxford102/blob/master/util.py")

Answer (score -3):

You might need to do like this:

```
from keras import backend as K
K.set_image_dim_ordering("th")
```